# How to connect with oracle through visual studio 2012 (windows 7 6bit)

Tags: oracle, odac

I want to connect with oracle using visual studio 2012 ultimate edition on windows 7 64 bit. I see documentation and help only for windows 7 32 bit. So please anyone guide me how to connect with oracle on windows 7 64 bit operation system, and which ODT-ODAC version for windows 7 64 bit should be used, thanks

Comment: Visual Studio itself is a 32 bit application. It depends on compile setting of your application whether you need the 32 bit or 64 bit version of ODP.NET. Here is an instruction how to install both: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100

Comment: When installing ODAC 64 bit on 64 bit machine i got an error(oracle services for microsoft transaction server failed installing) during installation.Please guide specially to this issue, that how can i get rid from this error, thanks

Comment: Nothing else? Please open a new question for this, at the moment I have no answer.

Comment: Thanks, Actually i downloaded (64-bit ODAC 12c Release 1) and install it again. Now its working, only problem is that i cannot see Oracle data source when adding Data Connection. I don't know either i am connecting through default .Net framework Data Provider for Oracle OR ODAC 12c Release 1, will investigate later, Appreciated your help :).

Comment: Please check this: [Oracle.DataAccess not available for selection in Visual Studio 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28537783/oracle-dataaccess-not-available-for-selection-in-visual-studio-2013/28543212?noredirect=1#comment45429139_28543212)