# Oracle Data Source missing from Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise

Tags: oracle, visual-studio

I'm trying to set up a connection (for the first time) to an Oracle database using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015. I've downloaded the latese 64 bit Oralce access components (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html).

I followed the instructions and run "install_odpm.bat c:\orcl x64" to install the components. I restarted Visual Studio, and tried to add a new model, but there is no Oracle data source option. How do I get this added?

Comment: Please check this answer: [Oracle.DataAccess not available for selection in Visual Studio 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28537783/oracle-dataaccess-not-available-for-selection-in-visual-studio-2013/28543212?noredirect=1#answer-28543212)

Comment: I followed that. It made no difference. I Still don't see Oracle. Surely there is a simple onclick installation way to do this?