# Can't find oracle database option in choose data source option of visual studio 2012 express edition

Tags: c#, database, oracle, visual-studio-2012, oracle10g

I want to connect oracle database with my c# application but the problem is i can not find oracle database option when try to select from 
Database explorer -> new connection -> choose data source -> no oracle database option is here. see the screenshot pleas. Help me please.
Note: Visual studion 2012 express edition and using oracle 10g.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2K3y.png)

Comment: This option is not available, because you have not installed a Oracle database driver. Install it from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/28543212/3027266 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/28695779/3027266